# Why can't I use a with variable in select?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

So I'm trying to calculate the population surround **Atlantic Commons**.

```sql
with atlantic_commons as (
    select geom 
    from nyc_streets 
    where name = 'Atlantic Commons'
),
ac_nearby_pop_per_sqr_meter as (
    select 
    sum(popn_total) / sum(st_area(ncb.geom)) as pop_per_sqr_meter 
    from nyc_census_blocks ncb
    join atlantic_commons ac on 
    ST_DWithin(ncb.geom, ac.geom, 50)
)
select (ac_nearby_pop_per_sqr_meter.pop_per_sqr_meter * 
power(50, 2) * 3.14159) + 
(ac_nearby_pop_per_sqr_meter.pop_per_sqr_meter * 
st_length(ac.geom) * 100) as estimated_pop_in_proximity_to_ac
from nyc_census_blocks ncb
join atlantic_commons ac on ST_DWithin(ncb.geom, ac.geom, 50)
group by ac.geom;
```

It gives me this error

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ac_nearby_pop_per_sqr_meter"
  Position: 295

Error position: line: 8 pos: 294
```

Not sure why I cannot use `ac_nearby_pop_per_sqr_meter.pop_per_sqr_meter` variable directly in calculation

Comment: Obviously there are `ac_nearby_pop_per_sqr_meter` aliases but no table `ac_nearby_pop_per_sqr_meter` following `from` clause for the outer(the belowest) query

Comment: Because CTE is kind of temporary view. You can not mention it in a query based just on the fact it exists in the DB.

Comment: ```nyc_census_blocks``` is table form the database ? you didn't use this table ```ac_nearby_pop_per_sqr_meter``` in join condition but used in select stmt

Comment: you need to reference the CTE alias in the from. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d965599f0bfd275209b6720f2c0f5e0b for a working version of the query (with geom disactivated because unavaliable on dbfiddle)